# Overflow when approximating activation functions in neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision, approximation

I am facing an issue for several days and I haven't found a solution yet. For cryptographic purposes (Homomorphic Encryption to be precise), I need to use polynomial approximations of the activation functions in a neural network.

My ANN is for now extremely simple (just learning XOR) as I have this issue. I have tried different approximations (Taylor, least square method, ...) but no matter the degree (I have been up to degree 9) my results fail as they increase dramatically during the computations.

My code is the following:

```
def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    y = np.copy(x)
    (m,n) = np.shape(y)
    if (deriv):
        for k in range(m):
            for i in range(n):
                y[k,i] *= (1-y[k,i])
    else:
        for k in range(m):
            for i in range(n):
                y[k, i] = (1. / (1 + math.exp(-y[k, i])))
    return (y)

def approx(x, deriv=False):
    y = np.copy(x)
    (m,n) = np.shape(y)
    if (deriv==True):
        for k in range(m):
            for i in range(n):
                y[k,i] = (1-y[k,i])
    else:
        for k in range(m):
            for i in range(n):
                y[k, i] = (1 / 2) + 1.73496*(y[k, i]/8) - 4.19407*((y[k, i] /8)**3) + 5.43402*((y[k, i] /8)**5) - 2.50739*((y[k, i] /8)**7)
    return (y)

################################

X = np.array([[0,0,1],
    [0,1,1],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
np.random.seed(1)
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

for j in range(10000):
    l0 = X
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0,syn0))
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,syn1))
    l2_error = y - l2
    l2_delta = l2_error*sigmoid(l2,deriv=True)
    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
    l1_delta = l1_error * sigmoid(l1,deriv=True)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

The values don't seem to go that far from 0, and my approximations seem to be ok, according to this graph:
[Least Squares Method approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm47X.png)

Do you have any clue where these growing errors (growing up to NaN) come from?

If it can help, by using the polynomial of degree 7 from least squares approximation method (shown in my picture), l1_delta and l2 reach NaN after 553 iterations of the loop (and start exploding two steps before)

**EDIT**:
I just found out something really strange. For both my sigmoid and my approximation, I use the same definition when `deriv==True`, which is basically `x = x*(1-x)`.

However, if I apply my approximation for the two weight vectors syn0 and syn1, but keep the true sigmoid for the feedforward part (while syntactically it is the same) then it works! What's even weirder is that my approximations are giving better results than the sigmoid (in the order: degree-3 better than degree-7 better than sigmoid) Is it normal? And where would this overflow issue come from then?

Comment: Please define your sigmoid function for us, since that's where you're using approximations.  Apart from that, I suspect the error is the way you're using the lines with the derivative. e.g.  `sigmoid(l2,deriv=True)`. I say this based on comparison with [Andrew Trask's Tutorial](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/), which you seem to be using code from.  Seems you're taking a sigmoid of a sigmoid.

Comment: Yes indeed I am using his example before going to more complex NN. My definition of sigmoid is simply return (1 / (1+math.exp(-x)).
Actually the NN learns pretty well with the exact definition of sigmoid, it fails only with approximation.

For the approximation though, I kept "return x*(1-x)" when deriv=True. Otherwise I compute the polynomial approximation

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post, to tell us the actual (approximation) function(s) you're using for the sigmoid.   Other than that, I recommend perhaps introducing a learning rate that is less than 1.

Comment: I added the sigmoid and the best approximator shown in the picture. The 'weird' design is probably not the best, but it is to fit the input data (not just a real number but a vector / matrix)

Comment: Ok...just my $.02:  (1) You're using polynomials, which are guaranteed to blow up for sufficiently large values of |x|, and 
 also (2) are not non-decreasing functions (like most other standard activation functions).  To deal with the first issue, you might try gradient clipping...or else abandon polynomials for some other approximation basis (maybe rational functions?).  To deal with the second...sorry, no idea; I wonder if it might be ill-posed as an optimization problem.  Good luck.  I'll watch this space for better answers!

Comment: I have to use polynomials for my future work and have to stick with it... For the blowing issue, actually this is what doesn't make sense (for me) because the values are in a small interval when using the exact sigmoid and should (I think) remain small with the polynomial as this one is a very good approximation for a bigger interval...
.
I actually edited my first post because I think I found where my problem comes from